# why is $state.current a blank object in angular controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to implement a component controller that uses the current state from the definition within ui-router config.

I'm using angular 1.6.1 with ui-router 0.3.2.

What I'm observing in debugging is that in the controller the state is basically an unpopulated object. It has the fields but no values.

But if I bind it to the scope and render in the UI, it has the correct values in the UI so I can only assume the values are bound into the current state some time after the controller is executed.

Is there some type of state initialisation even that needs to occur for the `current state` object to be populated in the controller?

`$state.current` definition at the point of the controller code execution:

`{"name":"","url":"^","views":null,"abstract":true}`

From the app bootstrap:

```
var userStates = [
{
  name: 'signin',
  url: '/signin',
  templateUrl: 'views/signin.html',
  data: {
    title: 'Signin',
    crumb: [
      {title: 'app.home', uiState: 'home'},
      {title: 'users.signin'}
    ]
  }
}
];

userStates.forEach(function(state){
  $stateProvider.state(state);
});
```

Then in the component definition file:

```
var app = angular.module('ocs.admin.ui');

var ctrl = ['$state', '$scope', 'lodash', function($state, $scope, lodash) {

  $scope.uiState = $state;

  var crumb = lodash.get($state, 'current.data.crumb');
  if (state){
    $scope.crumb = crumb;
  }

}];
```

And the HTML file is pretty simple at the moment:

```
<div class="page-breadcrumb">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Dashboard</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<pre>
    {{uiState.current | json}}
</pre>
```

Is there an event I should listen to or something that waits the for the object to be bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  $scope.uiState = $state;
});
```

Comment: cool. that event works, it's a bit clunky in code but working. Cheers. - can accept in 10 mins.